# how to get rid of side to side scroll

Tags: html, css

I can't find the problem and it's probably quite easy.

I have this side-to-side scroll

here's the test site: http://sgs.webparity.net

If you notice the NAV is 1860px as well as the BODY. BUT, there's a thin white margin of 20px which just will NOT go away.

There's no code here except for that on the INSPECT f12 of the BROWSER.

It's probably something really dumb.

A kind hand would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give overflow-hidden in css to your section having id="section-map". Right now your map is not loading due to some error. Once you fix that issue it would be more clear to fix this.

Solution to be put in your style.css

```
#section-map{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Absolute GENIUS. It's the SIMPLE THINGS. I need to put my google-maps KEY and the map will load.  Thanks... happy holidays to the both of you: Charlie and Rahul.